# how to develop charts with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am new  to Silverlight. I need to develop a Silverlight application along with charts.
Any idea how I should develop this thing? Any articles, code which tell me  how to  do it 
 that would be really great. Please  share your  thoughts how i can achieve this.

thank you

Comment: have you tried searching? what did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of exciting examples @ the below location

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the Silverlight Toolkit which has free charts: http://silverlight.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Visicharts have a nice set under GPL as well. 
    http://www.visifire.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will find plenty of very useful resources here:
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=silverlight

Answer (score 0):

What kind of charts are you trying to create? Basic charts or more complex 3D Charts (which the toolkit doesn't offer)

Whatever your taste, Telerik has a wide variety of drill-down charts including this [one](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/DrillDown) that you can play around with. You may want to start with this [page](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/FirstLook) and click the "Other Chart Examples" drop down to see what they have to offer.